# Crear select con html usando ajax

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, json

Intento crear un `select` en HTML5 trayendo los datos desde un archivo .js que tiene un `$.ajax` que llama a una URL que tiene datos en JSON.

Pero siempre tira para error: `function(data)` y no se por qué, la url está bien por lo que me imagino que será el código, os lo dejo a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="funciones_app.js"></script> 
</head>
<body onload="getData()">

<p>Sessions: 
<select id="Select"></select>


</body>
</html>
```

funciones_app.js

```js
function getData(){
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://.../json_tipo_productos.php', 
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
       alert("pepe");
       $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
        var id = "";
           var nombre = "";
           
      $.each(registro, function(key, value) {
       //alert(campo + ": " + valor);
       if (key == "id") { id = value; }
       if (key == "nombre") { nombre = value; }
              
      });
                 }); 
   $("#select").append('<option value='+id+'>'+nombre+'</option>');   
      },
      error: function(data) {
       alert('error');
      }
     });
}
```

El Json tiene este formato:

```
[{"id":"6","nombre":"FLORISTERIA"},{"id":"8","nombre":"JOYERIA"}
```

Intento crear el select en html como veis pero siempre aparece vacio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tu código tenia los siguientes errores:
>
> 1. `$("#select").append('<option value='+id+'>'+nombre+'</option>');`, esta fuera del primer `$.each`
> 2. El id del `<select>` empieza con mayuscula, es decir, deberias escribir `$("#Select")`.
> 3. `async: false,` esta deprecado, no lo uses.

Prueba esto:

```
function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://../json_tipo_productos.php', 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
        $("#Select").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
      });        
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
}
```

**Nota**: No dejo un snippet funcional porque tu server no soporta [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: antes que nada agradecer la respuesta. Hice tus modificaciones y me sigue saliendo el alert('error')...

Comment: es porque el server no soporta CORS, revisa la consola del DevTools

Comment: Lo integro y comento. gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Perfecto. Tu solucion es la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno *como sugerencia* el orden de tus `<script>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="funciones_app.js"></script>
```

Segundo, tu `<select>` la id es `Select` y no `select` y tercero, estas haciendo un `each` de más

```
$.each(data,function(key, registro) {
    $("#Select").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');                                          
});
```